# XSLT to DOCX (OOXML) - How to handle hyperlinks

Tags: xml, xslt, docx

I am trying to convert from XML to DOCX file, however I have a problem with hyperlinks (to external source) as it requires Relationship declaration in the `document.xml.rels`. Like so:

```
<Relationship Id="rId5" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink" Target="http://www.google.com/" TargetMode="External"/>
```

then I can reference this Relationship by it's id:

```
<w:hyperlink r:id="rId5">
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:color w:val="#0070BB"/>
      <w:i/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>
      <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
    </w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:hyperlink>
```

Is it possible to specify the link URL within the hyperlink tag, as an attribute? So I don't have so use another file...

Something like this:

```
<w:hyperlink external-url="http://...">
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:color w:val="#0070BB"/>
      <w:i/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>
      <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
    </w:t>
  </w:r>
</w:hyperlink>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not stuck on XSLT 1.0, you could you use `<xsl:result-document>`. That way you can have multiple outputs from one transformation.